# How can I change the stacking order of points and lines in a ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(mtcars)+
 geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)),fill='white',shape=21)+
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

Obviously, because I draw the points first and then the line, it caused the legend to show the line is above the dot

My requirement is to make the points above the line in legend. But when drawing, **still draw points first and then lines**

---

Expected legend（But not figure）

```
ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)))+
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)),fill='white',shape=21)
```

[image]

Comment: `legend to show the line is above the dot` << what does it mean?

Comment: Can you include a sketch showing the intended output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aware of any option to set the order in which the key glyphs are drawn. But one hacky approach to achieve your desired result would be to switch the key glyphs used, i.e. use `path` for `geom_point` and `point` for `geom_line`. This way we get the desired order but it requires some additional tweaks via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to set the `linetype`, `shape` and `fill` used to draw the glyphs:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  mtcars,
  aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = factor(cyl))
) +
  geom_point(
    fill = "white", shape = 21,
    key_glyph = "path"
  ) +
  geom_line(
    key_glyph = "point",
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      override.aes = list(
        linetype = "solid", fill = "white", shape = 21
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shape of legend using `guide`. Here is the sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = factor(cyl)), shape = 21) +
  geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 16)))
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

You can check list of shapes [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-point-shapes-best-tips/) or [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html)